# Receiving error with manifest.json (unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, json, manifest

I am trying to make an app i wrote progressive.

I am getting an error pointing to my manifest.json file...

The error says, `Line: 1, Column: 1, Unexpected Token`.

Here is my manifest file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Blah Blah Blah",
  "short_name": "Analysis App",
  "theme_color": "#fddb2f",
  "background_color": "#fddb2f",
  "display": "standalone",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "version": "1",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

And this is how i am referencing it in my html

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

I have no idea why i am getting this error??

Can anybody help??

Thanks a lot

Comment: i have the same issue

Comment: this link has solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187004/manifest-line-1-column-1-syntax-error-when-pushed-to-production/59203684?noredirect=1#comment104642681_59203684

Answer (score 3):

Try to use  href="./manifest.json" with the "." before /

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem but it is solved 50%.

I tested it google tutorial from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

When I setup it on web server for chrome with root folder (Choose folder = Current/pwa_weather ) It works 100%. I can access it like https://localhost:8888.

However, when I set it up to my Azure with accessing like https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/pwa_weather, it doesn't work.

I conclude menifest.json must be in web root folder. I failed even modifying manifest.json with utf8bom file format. Also, modifying index.html with absolute path like  , .