# Manifest Line 1, Column 1, Syntax Error when pushed to production

Tags: reactjs, manifest

First I have scoured the platform and google with no luck.

Getting a random Manifest error when I push to production.  With one push everything is fine.  With another, the error appears.  And when it errors all the icon links break.  I can't figure this out at all.  Any help is appreciated.

Served from https://zeit.com

live app:  https://ryancarville.com

repo:  https://github.com/ryancarville/portfolio-app

manifest code

```
{
  "short_name": "Full-Stack-Portfolio",
  "name": "Ryan-Carville-Full-Stack-Portfolio",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/bequia-logo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "204x156"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/camera.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "340x340"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/headphones.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/food.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/portrait.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/products.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/not-found.jpg",
      "type": "image/jpg",
      "sizes": "818x718"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your manifast.json file looks good.
the problem is with your server. when the browser is requesting for manifast.json file 404 page is served as response.
That is why syntax error.

Comment: Where are you seeing that?  In my DevTools Network tab I get a 200 for the manifest but with the error.

Comment: inspect your page there you will find <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"> try opening this link. this link should respond with json file but it respond with html. Html is not valid json so syntax error in line 1

Comment: Ahhh.  OK.  Will contact the server provider.  Thank you!  This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: What do you think is likely to be wrong with the server @shirish Maharjan?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it solved. In my app.js express backend folder I put index.html file by mistake

```
(app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../frontend/build/index.html")))
```

so after removing its working fine. Code should like below

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../frontend/build")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"../frontend/build/index.html")); }); }
```

Comment: Please place your code into a code block: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.